# Blackberry Textbox copy and paste

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to copy text from any running application's `textfield` and also edit that text field programmatically in blackberry? What i am trying to do is you have you text e.g. in `BBM` you have texted a msg and now you go to menu and click translate. My app copies the data from the focused textbox then translates it accordingly then pastes it back.